# How do I get my two audioplayers to play two different songs simultaneously?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, mpmediaitem

Okay so i will try to explain this as best as I can. My app has two audio players and I would like to be able to play a song from each of the players from my music library. The problem Im having is when I pick the first song to play it works and then when I pick another song it turns off the first song and both audio players only can play the song that was picked. How do I get the audio players to play two different songs? Here is the code I have currently:

```
 //EDITED CODE: 
class GameScene: SKScene, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController?
var mediaPicker2: MPMediaPickerController?

var music2 = MPMediaItem()
var music = MPMediaItem()

var musicPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer()
var musicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
mediaPicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

let aMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem
music = aMediaItem
NSLog("\(aMediaItem.title)selected")


let url: NSURL = (music.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL)!

    do {
        musicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)

    } catch {
        return
    }
        musicPlayer.pause()
        leftPlayButton.hidden = false




if mediaItemCollection.items.count > 1 {
    let aMediaItem2 = mediaItemCollection.items[1] as MPMediaItem
    music2 = aMediaItem2

    let url2: NSURL = (music2.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL)!

    do {
        musicPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url2)

    } catch {
        return
    }
    musicPlayer2.pause()
    rightPlayButton.hidden = false

}
 }
            if node.name == "addmusictoleft" {
            mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .Music)

            if let picker2 = mediaPicker{


                print("Successfully open media picker Left")
                picker2.delegate = self
                picker2.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true
                picker2.showsCloudItems = false
                picker2.prompt = "Pick a song for left player"
                self.view?.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(picker2, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                print("PICKER WONT OPEN")
            }
        }


            if node.name == "addmusictoright" {
            mediaPicker2 = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .Music)
            if let picker = mediaPicker2{


                print("Successfully open media picker Right")
                picker.delegate = self
                picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
                picker.showsCloudItems = false
                picker.prompt = "Pick a song for right player"
                self.view?.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                print("PICKER WONT OPEN")
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made demo project and it works fine in my iPad. 
Here is my code.

> ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>


@end
```

> ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController (){

int counter;

}

@property AVAudioPlayer *avAudioPlayer;
@property AVAudioPlayer *avAudioPlayer2;

@end

@implementation ViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];


counter = 0;
self.avAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
self.avAudioPlayer2.delegate = self;

UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 50, 80, 30)];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[button1 setTitle:@"play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button1];


UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 120, 80, 30)];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2Click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[button2 setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button2];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)button2Click : (id)sender {

if (counter == 0) {

    [self.avAudioPlayer stop];
}
if (counter == 1) {

    [self.avAudioPlayer2 stop];
}


counter ++;

 }

-(void)button1Click : (id)sender {

MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select songs to play";
mediaPicker.showsCloudItems = NO;

[self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


MPMediaItem *item = [[mediaItemCollection items]objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *myURL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];


NSError *err1;


self.avAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL error:&err1];


if (err1) {

    NSLog(@"@err1 : %@",[err1 localizedDescription]);

}


[self.avAudioPlayer play];


if ([mediaItemCollection items].count >1) {

    MPMediaItem *item2 = [[mediaItemCollection items]objectAtIndex:1];
    NSURL *myURL2 = [item2 valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    NSError *err2;
    self.avAudioPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL2 error:&err2];
    if (err2) {
        NSLog(@"err2 : %@",[err2 localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self.avAudioPlayer2 play];

}

 // NSLog(@"mediaitemCollection : %@",[mediaItemCollection items]);


}

-(void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil ];

}

@end
```

Click play button and pick two music files because we set `allowsPickingMultipleItems` to `YES`.

It works fine in my ipad. convert it in swift if you require. it is not difficult task i think.

Hope this solve your issue. :)

Comment: Thanks for the links but is there anything in swift I could look at?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It have one link for swift check it if it may help you.

Comment: I tried add these two lines of code to each of my if statements but it doesnt seem to work. Do you know how I could get this to work?             try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers)

Comment: You just need to make two different players and both should have different sound url. check above links and rebuild your code accordingly. i have updated my answer with little code hope it can help you.

Comment: I get an error for the line, it says argument labels do not match any available overloads.   if let newPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url, error:&error) {

Comment: I will try when i got time and will make demo to perform your requirement. :)

Comment: Thank you I still cant get it work for some reason. If you need a sample project of my code I can give it to you if that is easier.

Comment: If require then i will ask for that. If you want to post then you can..!

Comment: welcome dude.! is it mandatory to pick audio from music library ? Or you have fixed number of sounds file in project?

Comment: It's mandatory to pick from the music library because I'm making a dj app.

Comment: Okay. I'll try and informed you.

Comment: I have two buttons for each audio player to open the music library and pick a song for each player.

Comment: Hey i have updated my answer and it's working as you require. please try it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I try to pick a song for my left side it works but I cant pick a song for my audioplayer on my right side. I updated the code in my op can you take a look at it and see if im doing it right?

Comment: Why are you pausing your player?

Comment: Because I dont want it to play after I pick the song. I want to press play and then play the song. Btw I got it to work but is there a way I could pick two songs and the picker controller dismisses on its own?

Comment: I dont want the user to pick more than two songs.

Comment: According to my code you have to pick two music file at once. there should not two different button to pick music. If you want to pick music by two different buttons then give tag to both mediaPicker and put if in didfinidhPickmedia. and use let aMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem for both case.

Comment: Im using spritekit how would I use a tag?

Comment: You can put two different button and create two different mediaPicker for each button and set allowsPickingMultipleItems to NO. so one mediapicker only can pick one music file.

Comment: If you have fix number of mediaPicker then take it as a property. no need to set tag.

Comment: Can you take a look at my code I added it in the op?

Comment: Yes but Im trying to pick 2 songs and dismiss the pickercontroller or use two seperate buttons.

Comment: What i am saying, create two mediapicker, set allowsPickingMultipleItems to NO for both. then in didfinishpickmedia, put condition to check whether it is first mediapicker or second. pick music for both by let aMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem  and let aMediaItem2 = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem

Comment: You can use two buttons for that or can take only first two objects from collections if allow to pick multiple media at once or you can use same button for two time. There are many options you can perform... Cheers man ! :)

Comment: Im trying to get it to pick two songs and dismiss the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help!